# Forcing EventProcessorHost to re-deliver failed Azure Event Hub eventData's to IEventProcessor.ProcessEvents method

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-eventhub

The application uses .NET 4.6.1 and the [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.EventProcessorHost nuget package v2.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.EventProcessorHost/2.0.2/), along with it's dependency [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus package v3.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/3.0.1/) to process Azure Event Hub messages.

The application has an implementation of `IEventProcessor`.  When an unhandled exception is thrown from the `ProcessEventsAsync` method the `EventProcessorHost` never re-sends those messages to the running instance of `IEventProcessor`.  (Anecdotally, it will re-send if the hosting application is stopped and restarted or if the lease is lost and re-obtained.)

Is there a way to force the event message that resulted in an exception to be re-sent by `EventProcessorHost` to the `IEventProcessor` implementation?

One possible solution is presented in this comment on a nearly identical question:
[Redeliver unprocessed EventHub messages in IEventProcessor.ProcessEventsAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475881/redeliver-unprocessed-eventhub-messages-in-ieventprocessor-processeventsasync#comment60859252_36475881)

The comment suggests holding a copy of the last successfully processed event message and checkpointing explicitly using that message when an exception occurs in `ProcessEventsAsync`.  However, after implementing and testing such a solution, the `EventProcessorHost` still does not re-send.  The implementation is pretty simple:

```
private EventData _lastSuccessfulEvent;

public async Task ProcessEventsAsync(
    PartitionContext context,
    IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
{
    try
    {
        await ProcessEvents(context, messages);     // does actual processing, may throw exception
        _lastSuccessfulEvent = messages
            .OrderByDescending(ed => ed.SequenceNumber)
            .First();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        await context.CheckpointAsync(_lastSuccessfulEvent);
    }
}
```

An analysis of things in action:
[image]

A partial log sample is available here: https://gist.github.com/ttbjj/4781aa992941e00e4e15e0bf1c45f316#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: Chrisgh: Unlike Service Bus where messages can be leased individually; with Event Hubs, checkpointing event X means that all messages up to and including X (x-1, x-2, etc.) as assumed to have been processed successfully. Meaning that, in a parallel environment; you may fail to process message X-1 but successfully process message X, checkpoint, and never attempt to reprocess message X-1.  Is it possible that this scenario could be the root of the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: No, checkpoints, ie PartitionContext.CheckpointAsync(), only occur when all messages received by the IEventProcessor implementation are successfully processed.  The IEventProcessor implementation never checkpoints if there is an unhandled exception.  But if there is an unhandled exception the EventProcessorHost is never re-sending the "uncheckpointed" messages back to IEventProcessor.ProcessEventsAsync.

Comment: We've attempted to work around this by "re-checkpointing" X-1, i.e, the last successfully processed event message, via PartitionContext.CheckpointAsync(_lastSuccessfulEvent), but EventProcessorHost still does not re-send.  For clarity, this is tested with a single message on the partition at a time..

Comment: Your test clearly shows this is not the case here, but one point to be careful of is that the _lastSuccessfulEvent probably needs to be partition-specific. I.e, you would keep an ConcurrentDictionary<Guid> where the Guid was the partitioned and the value was the eventdata.

Comment: Agreed, but this was a proof-of-concept to validate whether retrial would occur by "re-checkpointing".  (It also should probably be ordering on the Offset in addition to the Sequence Number.)

Comment: I didn't dig deeper. but lil suggestion. How about Sending another Event by cloning the failed EventData from the failed event.

Comment: I believe that would result in duplicates for other consumers. Yes, those could be handled, but given this appears to be an issue with the host app and not the event hub itself, that's seems like a janky work around.

Comment: @RMD have you seen these? http://www.hivmr.com/db/sxa1a11dckmjjzpkd193d3x9zdsxdkz3 and http://www.hivmr.com/db/cc1mzcds8a88dpx1x1s3fcpakd193mzp

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TLDR**: The only reliable way **to re-play a failed batch of events to the `IEventProcessor.ProcessEventsAsync` is to - `Shutdown` the `EventProcessorHost`(aka `EPH`) immediately** - either by using `eph.UnregisterEventProcessorAsync()` or by [terminating the process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100(v=vs.110).aspx) - based on the situation. This will let other `EPH` instances to acquire the lease for this partition & start from the previous checkpoint.

Before explaining this - I want to call-out that, this is a **great Question** & indeed, was one of the toughest design choices we had to make for `EPH`. In my view, it was a trade-off b/w: `usability`/`supportability` of the `EPH` framework, vs `Technical-Correctness`.

**Ideal Situation** would have been: When the user-code in `IEventProcessorImpl.ProcessEventsAsync` throws an Exception - `EPH` library shouldn't catch this. It should have let this `Exception` - crash the process & the `crash-dump` clearly shows the `callstack` responsible. I still believe - this is the most `technically-correct` solution.

**Current situation**: The contract of `IEventProcessorImpl.ProcessEventsAsync` API & `EPH` is,

1. as long as `EventData` can be received from *EventHubs service* - continue invoking the user-callback (`IEventProcessorImplementation.ProcessEventsAsync`) with the `EventData's` & if the user-callback throws errors while invoking, notify `EventProcessorOptions.ExceptionReceived`.
2. User-code inside `IEventProcessorImpl.ProcessEventsAsync` should handle all errors and incorporate `Retry's` as necessary. `EPH` doesn't set any timeout on this call-back to give users full control over processing-time.
3. If a specific event is the cause of trouble - mark the `EventData` with a special property - for ex:type=`poison-event` and re-send to the same `EventHub`(include a pointer to the actual event, copy these `EventData.Offset` and `SequenceNumber` into the New `EventData.ApplicationProperties`) or fwd it to a SERVICEBUS Queue or store it elsewhere, basically, **identify & defer processing the poison-event**.
4. if you handled all possible cases and are still running into `Exceptions` - catch'em & shutdown `EPH` or `failfast` the process with this exception. When the `EPH` comes back up - it will start from where-it-left.

**Why does check-pointing 'the old event' NOT work** (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41867611/3277385) to understand `EPH` in general):

Behind the scenes, `EPH` is running a pump per EventHub Consumergroup partition's receiver - whose job is to start the receiver from a given `checkpoint` (if present) and create a dedicated instance of `IEventProcessor` implementation and then `receive` from the designated EventHub partition from the specified `Offset` in the checkpoint (if not present - `EventProcessorOptions.initialOffsetProvider`) and eventually invoke `IEventProcessorImpl.ProcessEventsAsync`. The purpose of the `Checkpoint` is to be able to reliably start processing messages, when the `EPH` process Shutsdown and the ownership of Partition is moved to another `EPH` instances. So, `checkpoint` will be consumed only while starting the *PUMP* and will **NOT** be read, once the pump started.

As I am writing this, `EPH` is at version [2.2.10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.EventProcessorHost/2.2.10).

[more general reading on Event Hubs...](https://medium.com/@sreeramg/what-is-microsoft-azure-event-hubs-1ec100452067)

Comment: The shutdown via UnregisterEventProcessorAsync was something that was considered and is the approach I'm leaning towards.  Thanks for your detailed response, which validates that approach.

Comment: Should we also retry when internal exceptions (like LeaseLostException, StorageException or EventHubException) are thrown? I dedicated a separate question to this and exception handling in general: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50953546/

Answer (score -2):

Simple Answer:
Have you tried [EventProcessorHost.ResetConnection(string partiotionId)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventprocessorhost#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventProcessorHost_ResetConnection_System_String_)?

Complex Answer:
It might be an architecture problem that needs to addressed at your end, why did the processing fail? was it a transient error? is retrying the processing logic is a possible scenario? And so on...

Comment: Processing can fail for a variety of reasons but that shouldn't force you to "lose" events. Indeed, event hubs as a whole don't ever record the fact you processed an event. You tell them where you want to start reading. They'll delete events after the retention period, but that's about it. If this is a problem, it's a problem caused by assumptions or bugs made by MS when they wrote the EventProcessorHost and not assumptions made when choosing event hubs in general.