# How to process the message on failure inside IEventProcessor.ProcessEvents method

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-eventhub, event-processor-host

The application has an implementation of IEventProcessor. When an unhandled exception is thrown from the ProcessEventsAsync method the EventProcessorHost never re-sends those messages to the running instance of IEventProcessor. (It will re-send if the hosting application is stopped and restarted or if the lease is lost and re-obtained.)

when an exception occurs in processEventAsync the checkpoint will not be set only if it's successful the checkpoint is set using this context.CheckpointAsync()

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006498/forcing-eventprocessorhost-to-re-deliver-failed-azure-event-hub-eventdatas-to-i

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [ProcessorErrorAsync](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/blob/master/samples/DotNet/ServiceFabricProcessor/ProgrammersGuide.md#processerrorasync) method. According the [doc](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/blob/master/samples/DotNet/ServiceFabricProcessor/ProgrammersGuide.md), it will be called in the event of an error. You'll have access to the context where can log the id and error.

Comment: But what I want to achieve is this when an exception occurs. go back and read from storage account and receive again. How can that be achieved